# $P$ non-constant polynomial, then there is for each $a>0$ there is $b>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

$P$ non-constant polynomial, then there is for each $a>0$ there is $b>0$ such that
$$(z:\left |  z\right |>b)\subseteq (P(z):\left | z \right |>a)$$

I'm not sure where to start or how to prove this statement, any help would be great.

Edit:
I first wrote $b<0$, which is clearly false. And as corrected, $b>0$ is right one.

Comment: Do you really mean $b<0$?

Comment: My bad. It is $b>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $z$'s in your two sets play different roles, so it might be better to write this as

$$ \{w: |w| > b\} \subseteq \{P(z): |z| > a \} $$

$\{P(z): |z| \le a\}$ is a compact set, so it is bounded.  Since the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus says $P$ is surjective, all you need to do is take $b$ so $\{P(z): |z| \le a\} \subseteq \{w: |w| \le b\}$, and then $ \{w: |w| > b\} \subseteq \{P(z): |z| > a \}$.

Comment: You mean Open mapping theorem or FTC?

Comment: I said FTC and I meant it.